# inside for loop if condition not working in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

`http://localhost.com:8000/dashboard/track_info/13/` this page have the dropdown there user can select country. If user return to the same page.. here i want to display selected country in default.

I tried with below but sadly not working...

```
<option value=""></option>
{% for country in country_list %}
<option value="{{ country.id }}" {% if country.id == get.territory_code_id %}  selected="selected" {% endif %}>{{ country.country_name | safe }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

`get.territory_code_id` coming from session and the value is 2

Can you spot the wrong here. ?

Comment: are you sure the value is an int 2 and not a string "2"

Comment: @StuartLeigh I don't know.. but the flow is ...| `{{ country.id }}` is `2` then `request.POST['territory_code']` will pick `2` only.. And finally i will save this value into session `request.session[event_id]['territory_code_id']`

Comment: I think you'll find `request.POST['territory_code']` is a string, try settings `int(request.POST['territory_code'])` to the session and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: @StuartLeigh Ya ... That's working... make ans..

Answer (score 0):

Writing up the solution in the comments -

Your country id is an integer `2`, whereas your territory code is a string `"2"`. That's why the equality test is not succeeding. You should cast your territory code to an integer (i.e., `int(request.POST['territory_code'])` ) before adding it to the session.