# condition to check if the value present in the list or not.?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I asked similar question yesterday [inside-for-loop-if-condition-not-working-in-django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386859/inside-for-loop-if-condition-not-working-in-django) but now i have checkbox to work

```
{% for items in store %}
<div class="col-xs-6"><input type="checkbox" value="{{ items.id|safe }}"{% if items.id in get.some_var %} checked="checked" {% endif %} name="store[]" id="check{{ forloop.counter }}" class="checkBox store">
<label for="check{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ items.name }}{{ items.id }}{{ get.some_var|safe }}</label>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

`get.some_var` coming from the session and value is `[u'1', u'3']`

and the `items.id` is `1` to etc ...

So if `1` is matching to `get.some_var` then the corresponding `checkbox` will `active` but sadly that is not working.

can you point what's wrong here .?

Comment: You should not be doing this. Django has a forms framework, you should use that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm doing wrong? i admit it but for the requirement i want to customize the page for the  client need so i am not using form here. And the workaround here is `User allowed to  select multiple check box in the page if user choose to return to that same page and i want to display user chosen check box`.

Comment: change `[u'1', u'3']` to this `[1,3]` and pass this into context processor and check.!